# Suspicious Activity in system.log OSX

Tags: macos, security

A mac user was having some clock errors, and thought they had seen someone using remote/VNC action on their screen. I went through the system.log and most of this activity is showing at times when the laptop was off and unplugged (no battery) and the user was asleep.

System.log file here- https://ghostbin.com/paste/mcukf

These were the lines that interested me.

**Java connection causing clock to be off.**

```
23:54:32 Ushas-Air Java Updater[531]: Original euid:501
Apr 24 23:54:32 Ushas-Air com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.preference.datetime.remoteservice[366]): Service exited due to signal: Killed: 9 sent by com.apple.preference.datetime.re[366]
Apr 24 23:54:32 Ushas-Air Java Updater[531]: Host name is javadl-esd-secure.oracle.com
Apr 24 23:54:32 Ushas-Air Java Updater[531]: Feed URL: https
Apr 24 23:54:32 Ushas-Air Java Updater[531]: Hostname check passed. Valid Oracle hostname
Apr 24 23:54:33 Ushas-Air com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.bsd.dirhelper[523]): Endpoint has been activated through legacy launch(3) APIs. Please switch to XPC or bootstrap_check_in(): com.apple.bsd.dirhelper
Apr 24 23:54:36 Ushas-Air java[541]: objc[541]: Class JavaLaunchHelper is implemented in both /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin/java (0x1023604c0) and /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/lib/jli/./libjli.dylib (0x119327480). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
```

**Instances of IMRemoteURLConnection Agent happening**

```
Apr 25 00:14:11 Ushas-MacBook-Air com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.imfoundation.IMRemoteURLConnectionAgent): Unknown key for integer: _DirtyJetsamMemoryLimit
Apr 25 00:01:22 Ushas-MacBook-Air com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.imfoundation.IMRemoteURLConnectionAgent): Unknown key for integer: _DirtyJetsamMemoryLimit
Apr 25 00:05:57 Ushas-MacBook-Air com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.preferences.users.remoteservice[762]): Service exited due to signal: Killed: 9 sent by com.apple.preferences.users.remo[762]
```

**Multiple cache deletes requested after.**

```
    Apr 25 00:01:27 Ushas-MacBook-Air logd[57]: _handle_cache_delete_with_urgency(0x7fdf19412a60, 3, 0)
Apr 25 00:01:27 Ushas-MacBook-Air logd[57]: _handle_cache_delete_with_urgency(0x7fdf19412a60, 3, 0)
Apr 25 00:01:31 Ushas-MacBook-Air com.apple.preferences.icloud.remoteservice[700]: BUG in libdispatch client: kevent[EVFILT_MACHPORT] monitored resource vanished before the source cancel handler was invoked
Apr 25 00:01:33 Ushas-MacBook-Air logd[57]: _handle_cache_delete_with_urgency(0x7fdf19658620, 3, 0)
Apr 25 00:01:33 Ushas-MacBook-Air logd[57]: _volume_contains_cached_data(is /private/var/db/diagnostics/ in /) - YES

Apr 25 00:01:34 Ushas-MacBook-Air logd[57]: 239517600 bytes of purgeable space from log files
Apr 25 00:01:34 Ushas-MacBook-Air logd[57]: _purge_uuidtext only runs at urgency 0 (3)
Apr 25 00:01:34 Ushas-MacBook-Air logd[57]: 0 bytes of purgeable space from uuidtext files
```

### And appears to be launching the FamilyCircleFramework

```
Apr 24 23:56:11 Ushas-Air com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.imfoundation.IMRemoteURLConnectionAgent): Unknown key for integer: _DirtyJetsamMemoryLimit
Apr 24 23:56:16 --- last message repeated 1 time ---
Apr 24 23:56:16 Ushas-Air familycircled[615]: objc[615]: Class FAFamilyCloudKitProperties is implemented in both /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FamilyCircle.framework/Versions/A/FamilyCircle (0x7fffbe466a60) and /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FamilyCircle.framework/Versions/A/Resources/familycircled (0x10aa01178). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
Apr 24 23:56:16 Ushas-Air familycircled[615]: objc[615]: Class FAFamilyMember is implemented in both /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FamilyCircle.framework/Versions/A/FamilyCircle (0x7fffbe466880) and /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FamilyCircle.framework/Versions/A/Resources/familycircled (0x10aa01268). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
Apr 24 23:56:16 Ushas-Air familycircled[615]: objc[615]: Class FAFamilyCircle is implemented in both /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FamilyCircle.framework/Versions/A/FamilyCircle (0x7fffbe466a10) and /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FamilyCircle.framework/Versions/A/Resources/familycircled (0x10aa01358). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
```

**Activity related to Findmyfriends happening. The mac owner doesn't use FindMyFriends, or have a mac phone.**

```
Apr 25 00:30:00 Ushas-MacBook-Air syslogd[40]: Configuration Notice:
    ASL Module "com.apple.mobileme.fmf1.internal" sharing output destination "/var/log/FindMyFriendsApp/FindMyFriendsApp.asl" with ASL Module "com.apple.mobileme.fmf1".
    Output parameters from ASL Module "com.apple.mobileme.fmf1" override any specified in ASL Module "com.apple.mobileme.fmf1.internal".
Apr 25 00:30:00 Ushas-MacBook-Air syslogd[40]: Configuration Notice:
    ASL Module "com.apple.mobileme.fmf1.internal" sharing output destination "/var/log/FindMyFriendsApp" with ASL Module "com.apple.mobileme.fmf1".
    Output parameters from ASL Module "com.apple.mobileme.fmf1" override any specified in ASL Module "com.apple.mobileme.fmf1.internal".
Apr 25 00:30:00 Ushas-MacBook-Air syslogd[40]: Configuration Notice:
```

### The keybaglogd being shared with com.apple.mkb

```
Apr 25 00:30:00 Ushas-MacBook-Air syslogd[40]: Configuration Notice:
    ASL Module "com.apple.mkb.internal" sharing output destination "/private/var/log/keybagd.log" with ASL Module "com.apple.mkb".
```

Comment: There is no question here...